# how to write method create in REST api (yii2) to add an object by condition

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I want to save new record to DB only if the same login and number are not used yet. But the code saves it to db even if the record with the same parameters is already exist

I write $model->save(); inside of conditions, but it saves anyway..
Code of whole Controller

```
  <?php
namespace app\modules\api\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use app\models\Client;
class ClientsController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Client';

      public function actionCreate(){
        $model = new Client();
        $login = $model->login;
        $carNumber = $model->carNumber;
        $result =null;
        if (!Client::findOne(['carNumber'=>$carNumber])){
            if(!Client::findOne(['login'=>$login])) {
                $model->save();
                $result = $model;
                return $result;
            }
            else {
                $result = "this login have been already used";
                return $result;
            }
        }
        else {
            $result = "this car number have been already used";
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add unique validation in model rules:

```
    public function rules()
    {
    return [
        [['login','carNumber'], 'unique'],
    ];
    }
```

And in actionCreate you should pass your attributes via a POST request, and then your action should become, for example:

```
public function actionCreate(){
    $model = new Client();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
      if ($model->save()) {
        return $model;
        }
      return $model->errors; //or whatever you want
    }
}
```

Further reading: [Yii2 Input validation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation)